# cognito oauth2 auth code grant provides access token but I need identity token

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

(I've rewritten this question because my original question formulation was very wrong. )

I just learned that an Access token is not suitable for authorizing a call to an aws apigateway method that is configured for a Cognito authorizer. This configuration only accepts an Identity token, not a Access token.

How can I authorize a apigateway call with a Access token?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm surprised that you say /{userpoolurl}/oauth2/token does not return id token. It returns 3 things in fact. { 'refresh_token': blah, 'access_token' : blah, 'id_token': blah }

Comment: No, @Deepthi, only returns an access token.  The doc  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html  appears to be wrong.  Or, perhaps, you get different results if using the client authentication grant type, vs, in my case, AUTHORIZATION_CODE.

Comment: @Deepthi, I apologize, you are right and I was wrong. I've rewritten the question.

Comment: Actually, with OAuth2, Cognito returns the ID token and Access Token. The only thing it doesn't return is the Refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of AWS support I have the answer.

If you want to use access tokens (vs identity tokens) with an api gateway configured for cognito authorization, you must:

1) define a resource server on the user pool.  The resource server definition logically identifies a resource (like an api gateay, or a custom api), and also defines custom scopes that qualify actions that a caller can perform on that resource. You might define a single scope, if all callers have the same privileges.

2) on the app client settings of the user pool, you will now see your custom scope listed below the list of standard scopes.  If you want a application that uses this custom client to have the privileges implied by the custom scope, you checkmark that scope.

3) in the api gateway definition, on a resource method (like GET, PUT, or POST), specify the scope(s) that are allowed access to this method on this resource.

That's it. For more, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html